# The results of my simulation are non-intuitive

Tags: perl, math, probability

A simple question has been bugging me and I don't know how to do the mathematics to prove it, so I wrote a simple Perl program to approximate an answer and I just don't agree with its results.

Am I wrong or is my script lacking something?

#### Problem

10 pairs of identical socks, except they're either left or right. If they're paired randomly, what is the probability of a correct pairing versus an incorrect pairing?

#### Update

*I meant if blindfolded I paired all the 20 socks in the drawer, what would be the ratio of correct pairs to incorrect pairs?*

My script indicates about 1.12 to 1 correct to incorrect ratio.

Is it right?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#SockCruncher

#use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @tumble_dryer = (R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,L,L,L,L,L,L,L,L,L,L);
my @rand_socks = shuffle(@tumble_dryer);
my $sock_pop1;
my $sock_pop2;
my $pair_counter = 1;
my @rev_rand_socks;
my $good_pair = 0;
my $bad_pair = 0;
my $counter = 0;

open (OUT,'>pairing.txt') or die ("Can't open pairing.txt for writing\n");
print OUT "Sock Sorter\n-----------\n\n";
print OUT "10 pairs of socks all identical appart from them being either left or right.  10 left & 10 right.\n";
print OUT "The 20 socks are shuffled in an array and the first 2 popped out.\n";
print OUT "The remaining socks are shuffled again and the first 2 popped out..... and so on.\n\n";

while ($counter < 100000) {

    while ($pair_counter <= 10) {
        print OUT "Socks : ";
        print OUT join(",", @rand_socks);
        @rev_rand_socks = reverse @rand_socks;  #Just done so the output file looks better. The LHS 2 elements are popped and eventually spliced off.
        $sock_pop1 = pop @rev_rand_socks;
        $sock_pop2 = pop @rev_rand_socks;
        print OUT " (P$pair_counter : $sock_pop1.$sock_pop2)   ";
        if (($sock_pop1 eq "L") && ($sock_pop2 eq "R")) {$good_pair = $good_pair +1;}
        if (($sock_pop1 eq "R") && ($sock_pop2 eq "L")) {$good_pair = $good_pair +1;}
        if (($sock_pop1 eq "L") && ($sock_pop2 eq "L")) {$bad_pair = $bad_pair +1;}
        if (($sock_pop1 eq "R") && ($sock_pop2 eq "R")) {$bad_pair = $bad_pair +1;}
        splice @rand_socks, 0, 2;
        @rand_socks = shuffle(@rand_socks);
        $pair_counter = $pair_counter + 1;
    }
    print OUT "  Good pairs : $good_pair   Bad pairs : $bad_pair\n";
    $counter = $counter + 1;
    $pair_counter = 1;
    @tumble_dryer = (R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,L,L,L,L,L,L,L,L,L,L);
    @rand_socks = shuffle(@tumble_dryer);
}
my $ratio = $good_pair/$bad_pair;
print "\nGood pairs = $good_pair  Bad pairs = $bad_pair    Good pair to bad pair ratio : $ratio.\n";
close (OUT);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem. It would be more appropriate on *Code Review*.

Comment: @Borodin I'm guessing the question is how often you will get *all* correct pairs if you pull out all 20 socks 2 at a time?  but it certainly isn't clear, and that isn't quite what the code does

Comment: I don't see why this bothers you. Having taken one sock, there are ten remaining socks which will match and nine which will not. The ratio is 10:9 or 1.11... But your code needs some work and you should submit it to [***Code Review***](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to be put on-track to write better code. In particular, declaring *every* variable in a block at the top of your program is damaging and indicative of a very old-fashioned style. It pretty much nullifies the advantages of `use strict`, which should only ever be commented out in private and without fear of interruption!

Comment: @ysth: Ah I see. Thank you, I had become sheep-like and assumed another variant of all previous sock/ball/marble blind-draw problems. As you say the problem isn't properly defined. I guess *"If they're paired randomly"* needs elaboration. But not here!

Comment: I'm not a programmer like you guys.  I'm very happy to have the logic explained as mob did.  The code was essentially functional, and I was wondering if there were mathematical errors contained within it.

Comment: @Pete: *"I'm not a programmer like you guys"* Writing software makes you a programmer, and your questions on *Stack Overflow* are subject to the same scrutiny as anyone else's. You mustn't hide behind a "not a real programmer" shield in the hope of escaping critique. You have clearly learned a lot, and I suggest you continue your study so that you can better respect your own work. You should think of Stack Overflow as being like Wikipedia: it is a repository of question and answer facts, and you should be at least competent in your work.

Comment: I'd encourage you to also work this out with pen and paper :)

Answer (score 1):

Say you pick out an R sock from the drawer.

Now there are 10 L socks left (which would make a correct pairing)

and there are 9 R socks left (incorrect pairing)

So 10 correct : 9 incorrect is about  1.11:1.

You didn't say what number you were expecting but if your script says 1.12:1, that is close to the correct results.

Comment: I had reasoned that if I pull out an R and an L it would leave behind an equal number of Rs and Ls, so still equal odds of pairing next time. But if I pull out, say, 2x Rs it leaves an unbalanced remainder which would slightly favour an incorrect pairing.  My script pairs 2 at a time and then reshuffles.

Comment: I can now see mob's logic and agree that's how it works.  Good enough for me.  Faulty logic on my part.  Cheers.

Comment: @Pete: *"My script pairs 2 at a time and then reshuffles"*. There is no need to reshuffle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the question is how often you will get all correct pairs if you pull out all 20 socks 2 at a time? But it certainly isn't clear, and that isn't quite what the code does.  You seem to be totalling up good pairs and bad pairs found in your inner loop, intead of totalling up good results vs bad results after the inner loop.

There is no point in reshuffling each time you've removed socks.

Try to declare variables in the smallest scope possible.

FWIW here's what I would have done:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my $attempts = 1000000;
my $pairs = 10;
my @socks = (('R') x $pairs, ('L') x $pairs);

my $correct_pairings = 0;
for my $attempt (1..$attempts) {
    my $picked_socks = join '', shuffle @socks;
    ++$correct_pairings if $picked_socks =~ /^(?:(.)\1){$pairs}/;
}
print "$correct_pairings correct pairings in $attempts attempts\n";
```

which shows getting 10 matched pairs less than .14% of the time.

Comment: I wasn't actually meaning that.  I meant if blindfolded I paired all the 20 socks in the drawer, what would be the ratio of correct pairs to incorrect pairs?

Comment: @Pete: That sounds exactly like what **ysth** has assumed. It's not what your question says. (I've added an update to your question that reflects the words of your clarification here.)

Comment: @Borodin no, sounds to me like I was wrong, and he does want total ratio of paired to unpaired socks, but for when you do remove all the pairs, not just the first (though from his results, the number is the same)

Comment: @ysth: I thought that was your original interpretation; it certainly sounds the same, but your code throws all socks back in the drawer before picking another pair.